# MySQL count - attribute repeats itself more than once

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

My MySQL table (:students) structure is as follows:
id, version, count

My table looks like this:

```
id   version  count
1    James    8
2    Dan      3
3    Alice    2
4    James    1
5    James    3
6    Dan      5
```

I am trying to get the count of number times "James" has obtained a count equal or under 5.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS version FROM students WHERE version='James' and count <=5
```

But I'm not getting any output. Am I missing something here?

Comment: **[SQLFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18605/1/0)** Show your table creation script.

Comment: Your query works for me.

Comment: Works for me too - there's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7119/1).

Comment: I can confirm that it works. It was my bad - The attribute (count) type was not set to integer.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put the ; at the end of your query statement! Code should look as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS version 
FROM students 
WHERE version='James' and count <=5;
```

Comment: When executing a single query a semicolon is not required on the end.